# Ckeditor is not functioning properly?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

#### Question

How come my ckeditor is not functioning?

#### Error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined" 
https://prnt.sc/ttqdm8

#### Version

ckeditor_4.14.1_full

#### File Structure

https://prnt.sc/ttqg7w

#### Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>File Manager Integration</title>
  <script src="./plugin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" data-sample-short>&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href=&quot;https://ckeditor.com/&quot;&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
  <script>
    // CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
      height: 300,


      filebrowserBrowseUrl: './plugin/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
      filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: './plugin/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
      filebrowserUploadUrl: './plugin/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
      filebrowserImageUploadUrl: './plugin/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions. The problem is caused by the folder name. Directly change the folder name from

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\testingProject\copypasteeditor --> D:\xampp\htdocs\testingproject\copypasteeditor
```

Change testingProject to testingproject.